# Convert text file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to turn a txt file with this format:

```
valido;válido
invalidos;inválidos
avaliacao;avaliação
nao e;não é
```

into this with Python:

```
{'valido': 'válido', 'nao e': 'não é', 'invalidos': 'inválidos', 'avaliacao': 'avaliação'}
```

My code so far:

```
final = []
with open("fich_teste.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        key; value = linha.sprit().split(';')
        final[key] = value
        return final
```

This returns an error:

```
builtins.NameError: global name 'key' is not defined
```

Comment: replace ; with ,
rather than `key; value` DO `key, value`

Comment: After that, you should actually define `final` as a dict (`{}` not `[]`) and also unindent the `return` line or you will always have just one item in your dict. Also, check out [pt.so], might be more convenient to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign values using `key, value` not `key; value` and fix some indentation problems along with the `final` declaration and method name:

```
def myFunc():
    final = {}
    with open("fich_teste.txt", 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.strip().split(';')
            final[key] = value

    return final
```